# Как select заменить на input если в базе одна запись?

Tags: php, mysqli

В форму подставляю select для выбора, но не всегда в базе несколько записей. Получается, если одна запись, то все равно появляется select.

Мой код:

```
//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT CASE WHEN pin_code.code IS NULL THEN 'trush' WHEN destroy_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) THEN '0' ELSE '1' END AS status FROM (SELECT '$pin_code' code) src LEFT JOIN pin_code USING (code)");  

if($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

if($row["status"] == '0'){

//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, item_name, amount, currency_code, custom, payment_service, business, stripe_pkey, status FROM subscription WHERE status = '1'");

$services = [];
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
if ($row["payment_service"] == 'PayPal'){
    
    $paypal_item_number = $row["id"];
    $paypal_amount = $row["amount"];
    $paypal_curr_code = $row["currency_code"];

    $services[$row["id"]] = $row;
    
  $money[] = <<<HTML
  <option value="$paypal_item_number">$paypal_curr_code $paypal_amount</option>
HTML;


}

}


// Include paypal form
include __DIR__ . '/forms/paypal.php';


}
}
```

Форма:

```
<form action="<?php echo PAYPAL_URL; ?>" method="post">
                    <input name="cmd" value="_xclick" type="hidden">
                    <input name="no_shipping" value="1" type="hidden">
                    <input name="item_number" value="1" type="hidden">
                    <select id="PayPalAmount" required class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Choose Payment Service</option>
<?php                           
foreach( $money as $key => $value ) {
    print  $value;
}
?>  
                    </select>
                    <div class="col-sm" id="select"></div>

                    <input name="return" value="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>" type="hidden">
                    <input name="cancel_return" value="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>" type="hidden">
                    <!-- Where to send the paypal IPN to. -->
                    <input name="notify_url" value="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>" type="hidden">        
                    
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="PayPalButton">
    Buy Now With PayPal        
</button>       
</form>
```

Пробовал использовать `is_array` но ничего не получилось.

Как избавиться от select если запись одна?

Спасибо.

Comment: прям совсем избавиться? или что-то вместо него должно быть?

Comment: Заменить на input name="id" value="значение"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name="cmd" value="_xclick" type="hidden">
<input name="no_shipping" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="item_number" value="1" type="hidden">

<?php if (count($money) > 1): ?>
    <select id="PayPalAmount" required class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose Payment Service</option>
        <?php foreach( $money as $key => $value ): ?>
            print  $value;
        <option value="<?= $key; ?>"><?= $value; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>      
    </select>    
<?php else: ?>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?= $money; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Не знаю, вместо `$money` в конце возможно должно быть `$money['XXXX']` ?

Comment: Да, $money['0']. Спасибо!